How to calculate speed of water current?
Bob swam across the Gibraltar strait, at the narrowest point where the strait is 14 km wide. Water flows through the strait. The direction of the water current is constant.
The swim took into account the water current. The distance swam through the water was 18 km and the swim took 5 hours.
How fast was the current of water through the strait at the time?
This is what I have tried but I don't think the answer is correct.
Bob swam 18 kilometers in 5 hours so we get 18km/5h=3.6km/h.
The speed is affected by the current, so the speed is the difference between Bobs swimming speed and the current speed which is 14km/5h=2.8km/h.
3.6-2.8 = 0.8 kilometers per hour.
Therefore, the speed of the current through the Gibraltar Strait at the time was 0.8 kilometers per hour.

How did you take in account that the two velocities are  in 90°?

The swimmer's ground speed across the strait is the result of combining two perpendicular velocity components:
The swimmer's own speed through the water which is in the direction the swimmer is aiming for.
The current speed which moves the swimmer laterally along the strait.
These two velocities combine to produce the swimmer's actual velocity over the ground, which can be found using the Pythagorean theorem

So you know the right way of calculating!

No idk the right way beacuse some of my classmates got the answer 2.26km/h for the speed of the current while I only get 0.8km/h. So I was hoping maybe someone could verify if I have calculated this correctly.

You cannot just subtract as if these were velocities in the same direction. Approach it this way: Ignoring the current, you swim to a point $18$ units away on the opposite bank. This gives a right triangle with one leg $14$ and hypotenuse $18$. The resulting leg along the opposite bank then has length $8\sqrt2$. The current will account for this displacement, so the speed of the current is $\dfrac{8\sqrt2}5\approx 2.26$ km/hr.
